# How to get wx stock bitmaps into wx ArtProvider

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

It says [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/stock_items.html#stock-items) in the wx stock item documentation that:

> ... you can retrieve stock bitmaps using wx.ArtProvider.

but in the [wx.ArtProvider documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ArtProvider.html) there is a very limited set of resources.

I would like to use some of the stock items in a toolbar (e.g. wx.ID_PREFERENCES)

How can I do this?

(I know how to get the bitmap into the toolbar, my question relates to getting the bitmap into the wx.ArtProvider)

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive the bitmaps using "wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap()".

For example :

```
bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_MENU)
```

Regards
Xav'

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer the question. How do a get a bitmap from wx.ID_PREFERENCES?

Comment: You can't get bitmaps from wx.ID_xxx . As you can see in the sample line I wrote, wxArtProvider's bitmaps are referenced by wx.ART_xxx. Have a look at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_art_provider.html#artprovider_identify : you'll get the list of available bitmaps. You can also create your own "library" of bitmaps with your own IDs. (see the sample code at the top of the related doc page).

Comment: so when the documentation says "... you can retrieve stock bitmaps using wx.ArtProvider." it is wrong?

Comment: Well, it is not really wrong : it says you can retreive stocks bitmaps, but it never says you can retreive them using stock IDs.

Comment: Ok. But it is misleading. That statement comes in a page with a whole list of stock bitmaps, most of which cannot be accessed through the ArtProvider